# mosquitto broker gives error when receiving MQTT connect packet (python)

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm currently working on a project in which I have to implement a MQTT client.

I won't list the code for the whole class that implements the Connect Package as it's quite long, but the message it generates when converted to bytes is:

```
bytearray(b'\x10\x10\x00\x04MQTT\x05\x02\x00<\x00\x04digi')
```

I have tried sending the packet using socket:

```
connect_package = ConnectPacket(60,"digi")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',1883))
s.sendall(connect_package.pack())
```

`connect_package.pack()` returns the bytearray mentioned earlier

However, the mosquitto client responds in the following way:

```
1607186254: mosquitto version 2.0.0 starting
1607186254: Config loaded from .\mosquitto.conf. 
1607186254: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883. 
1607186254: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883. 
1607186254: mosquitto version 2.0.0 running 
1607186273: New connection from 127.0.0.1:58295 on port 1883.
1607186273: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

I've tried to search for solutions but found nothing similar to my case.
I'm relatively new to Python so any critique is welcome, I'm here to learn.

Later edit:
this is the capture in Wireshark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlVRh.jpg 
and this is the class: https://pastebin.com/LuGTARE6

Comment: Edit the question to break down how you built that connect packet, what flags you set, what sizes you have included. Also I suggest you use something like wireshark to intercept the packets, it has a build in MQTT decoder which will show you if the packet matches what you expected to create.

Comment: The Connect packet also looks too short as a minimal static + variable header is 12bytes if I've done my maths right before you add the payload with the client id

Comment: The only flag that is set is Clean Session. I ll post the class and the capture in Wireshark soon.

Comment: This question may also be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088631/creating-a-thin-mqtt-publisher-without-using-a-stack-how-to

Comment: https://imgur.com/gzY0of6
this is the capture in Wireshark
and this is the class: https://pastebin.com/LuGTARE6

Comment: also, the packet that is sent is 18 bytes long.

Comment: it seems that the length of the client id that is read is actually too big: https://imgur.com/a/tgjTzZa

Comment: fonnd the problem, the Connect packet was missing the "Property Length" byte so the broker was expecting a client id with a length of 1124 bytes ( read the last 0x00 as property length, then 0x04 as MSB of Client ID length. Many thanks, @hardillb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that I have constructed my package without including the "Property Length" byte, so the broker was reading the last \x00 as Property Length, then it read \x04 as the MSB of the Client_ID length, so it was expecting a client with an id of at least 1124 bytes ( 00000100 -> 0x04 01100100 -> 'd'), but I was only providing 4.
Many thanks to hardillb.